# Why does the order of rows in my table change after calling location.reload(); when closing a modal box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, entity-framework-6, server-side

I have a link in my table for example a name in the  as a link so when I click on the link that persons details pop up in a modal box . The problem I am having is after I close the modal the row ordering in the table changes and this is a problem because when I click on another name(link) it comes up with the wrong id and hence displays the wrong details for that person

**Code for the modal that pops up when the link is clicked**

```
<script>

        $(function () {
            $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
                debugger;
                var $buttonClicked = $(this);
                var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
                var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { "Id": id },
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                        $('#myModal').modal(options);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                    }
                });
            });


            $("#closebtn").click(function () {
                $('#myModal').hide();
                //e.preventDefault();
                location.reload(false);

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear.  Your code doesn't appear to do anything about loading the initial name links in the table that you're clicking.

Are the ids correctly associated with each person when you click the first one on a newly loaded page?

The Javascript you have doesn't appear to impact anything that has to do with the way the the initial table data is structured. Without a working example and a more complete version of the markup for the entire page, people won't be able to help much, it's only speculation.

Since the incorrect ID is being passed when people are clicked, I would start tracking and debugging from there.  Remove the functions you're calling when the ajax request is successful and log the ID of the entity that is clicked.  Then confirm the data is correct for that ID by issuing the same request you're making via ajax.

If all of that checks out, I would look in other areas of your code that do or would impact the data attributes for the links.  Again, this is all speculation as I don't have a complete example to look at.